# ManyToMany select query in JPA2(JPQL)

Tags: many-to-many, criteria, jpql

I have two tables: User and Role in ManyToMany relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

//getters, setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long roleId;

    @Column(name = "role_code")
    private String roleCode;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<User> users;

//getters,setters

}
```

I want select all users and ALL HIS roles if user have role for example 'ROLE_USER'.

I did it in native sql but i would like to use JPQL or CriteriaQuery.

I tried in JPQL(changing earlier fetching type to EAGER becouse in subquery I can't use join fetch):

```
public List<User> findUsersByRole(String roleName, int startNumber, int endNumber) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("select u from User u join fetch u.roles r WHERE u.userId in (SELECT uu.userId FROM User uu join uu.roles rr WHERE rr.roleCode like :roleName)")
            .setParameter("roleName", roleName)
            .setFirstResult(startNumber)
            .setMaxResults(endNumber);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

and it works as I want but is it possible without changing Fetching type to EAGER?
Thank you for response.

Comment: This not work? `select u from User u join fetch u.roles join u.roles r WHERE r.roleCode like :roleName`. If works for you, I answer the question with more details about the jpql.

Comment: Yes, it's works now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
public List<User> findUsersByRole(String roleName, int startNumber, int endNumber) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("select u from User u join fetch u.roles join u.roles r WHERE r.roleCode like :roleName")
            .setParameter("roleName", roleName)
            .setFirstResult(startNumber)
            .setMaxResults(endNumber);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```